# Intersection of Family of Uncountably many Countable sets countable.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given a family of uncountably many countable sets (say Ai is countable for all for all i∈R)

I feel the intersection of these countable sets must be countable, but I am having a bit of trouble formally proving it.

Comment: Hints: a subset of a countable set is countable; an intersection of a family of sets is a subset of any member of the family.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $R$ be an uncountable indexing set. Notice
 $$ \cap_{i \in R} A_{i}\subseteq A_{i}$$  for each $i \in R$.
But since for each $i \in R$ , $A_{i }$ is countable $$ \cap_{i \in R} A_{i}$$ is countable.

Comment: Doesn't this imply that all Ai are the same size, Which may not be true?

Comment: @mathman No. This has nothing to do with the sizes of each $A_i$ other than that they are countable. I don't see how this infers what you are claiming.